# Blanket implementation of core traits constrained by locally-defined public trait

Tags: rust, traits

I have the following code:

```
pub trait GetIdentifier {
    //...
}
impl<T: GetIdentifier> Hash for T {
     fn hash(&self) -> //....
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::hash::Hash` for type `&_`:
  --> <anon>:18:1
   |
18 | / impl<T: GetIdentifier> Hash for T {
19 | | }
   | |_^
   |
   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`

error[E0210]: type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type (e.g. `MyStruct<T>`); only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter
  --> <anon>:18:1
   |
18 | / impl<T: GetIdentifier> Hash for T {
19 | | }
   | |_^
```

Why?  I haven't implemented `GetIdentifier` for `&_`, so the blanket `impl` shouldn't apply to `&_`.  Consumers of my crate wouldn't be able to implement `GetIdentifier` for core types either, so no problem there.  What am I missing here?  Why is `&_` even involved here -- I didn't put an `?Sized` bound on my trait so references shouldn't even be considered....right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consumers of your crate might implement `GetIdentifier` for `TheirType` and simultaneously implement `Hash` for `TheirType`.

Now you might say that's their problem, but imagine another crate with a trait `Foo` that also does `impl<T: Foo> Hash for T {}`, and `TheirType` implementing `Foo` and `GetIdentifier`. Suddenly they can't implement either trait.

The reason the error occurs for `&_` is that the stdlib impl says any type `T` implementing `Hash` causes `&T` to also implement `Hash`.

Comment: From what I understand, the OP states that `GetIdentifier` is a local trait, and thus cannot be implemented from outside.

Comment: I think the trait is public, because otherwise one would not need to make a distinction between core types and custom types

Comment: @E_net4 I meant locally-defined, public trait -- I'll update the question

Comment: This makes sense -- follow-up question:  if the trait is private, I *still* get the error.  Is there a reason for that, or is there some rule that says marking a `private` trait `public` shouldn't cause code not to compile?

Comment: visibility changes nothing, because through some indirection or another you might end up with the same problem. Rust doesn't do any global analyses. All the analyses are local in some sense or another.

Comment: @user1935361: Also, if that blanket impl was allowed and you implemented `GetIdentifier` on a standard library type that already implements `Hash`, that type would end up with two impls of `Hash`.